# Senha ao executar comando postgresql

Tags: postgresql, administração-postgresql

Bom dia,

estou tentando criar um banco no postgresql via terminal no windows. Porém me pede uma senha cada vez que dou o comando. Tentei usar a senha do usuário postgres mas não aceita. Alguém pode me ajudar?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Tens de mudar o teu "Role" de utilizador que pertence aquela base de dados.
Ou seja, mudar a permissão de utilizador, para não pedir sempre a pass.

Comment: Marcelo, é necessário que você forneça mais detalhes, como o comando utilizado e os parâmetros informados. Por exemplo, você tem a opção de informar com qual usuário deseja realizar o comando, o que poderia fazer diferença na hora em que você fornece a senha para que ela corresponda ao usuário que executará o comando.

Comment: Estou tentando o seguinte comando: `create user -U adempiere adempiere`

Comment: @RafaelAraújo na imagem acima tem o comando, outros detalhes, é que o cliente e servidor estão na mesma máquina que é um Windows 7 x64 e a versão do postgres é a 9.4

Comment: Marcelo, o comando para criar o banco é `createdb` (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-createdb.html). Para o exemplo que você deu, seria `createdb -U adempiere adempiere`. A senha a ser informada, então, é a do usuário *adempeiere*  que já deve pré-existir no banco de dados.

Comment: @Rafael Araújo concordo que para criar o banco o usuário deve pré-existir, porém quando tento adicionar o usuário (primeiro passo), ele pede a senha

Comment: @MarceloPrado, perceba, então, que você está com um problema no comando anterior ao relatado. O comando createdb não pode ser executado usando um usuário que você quer criar. O uso de `-U adempiere` significa que você quer se conectar usando o usuário **adempiere** e por isso que não aceita a senha do `postgres`. Para usar o usuário `postgres` na criação do novo usuário, o comando é `createuser -U postgres -d -l adempiere` (permite realizar login e criar banco de dados).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para criar um novo `usuario/role` no `PostgreSQL`, você precisa do comando [`CREATE ROLE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/sql-createrole.html), por exemplo:

```
CREATE ROLE adempiere LOGIN NOSUPERUSER INHERIT CREATEDB CREATEROLE;
```

Para criar um novo `usuário/role` através do terminal do `Windows` você pode usar o utilitário [`pgsql`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/app-psql.html), veja só:

```
psql -U postgres -c "CREATE ROLE adempiere LOGIN NOSUPERUSER INHERIT CREATEDB CREATEROLE;"
```

Comment: consegui criar o usuário com o último comando seu. Obrigado!